# Image processing in Python – without loading the entire image into memory

Tags: python, image-processing, memory-management, numpy, scipy

I'm looking for a python library that would allow me to retrieve image data from TIF images without loading the whole image into memory.

I have tried to use `numpy.memmap` but I’m having difficulties locating the image data in the file. Any advice would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: how big is the image?

Comment: Try `pyvips` - it is very fast and frugal on memory.

Answer (score 0):

I have two recommendations for you:

1. Read the image data into Python in chunks:

   ```
   with open('path/to/image-data.tif', 'rb') as tif:
       while True:
           chunk = tif.read(4096)
           if not chunk:
               break
   ```
2. Consider using **NumExpr** for your processing: https://github.com/pydata/numexpr

... internally, NumExpr employs its own vectorized virtual machine that is designed around the chunked-read strategy, in order to efficiently operate on optimally-sized blocks of data in memory. It can handily beat naïve NumPy operations if tuned properly.

Hope this helps, and good luck